# The preimage of a non surjective map

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

I am wondering what the preimage of a certain set with non surjective map would be.

Say $X=\{0,1,2\}$ with discrete topology and $Y=\{0\}$. If I have a map $f:Y \to X: 0 \to x$. I can specify something like $f(0)=0$ say. Then the preimage $f^{-1}(0)=\{0\} \in Y$ but what about the preimage $f^{-1}(1)$? Nothing is mapped to $1$ from $Y$ so, how can I think about this? Or say $U=\{1,2\} \subseteq X$. Preimage $f^{-1}U$ is....?

Confused with problems like this, can someone tell me what it would be? Is it the null set? Then is it true that $f(\phi)=U \subseteq X$?

Comment: Just follow the definition. If $f:X\to Y$, and $A$ is a subset of $Y$ disjoint from $f[X]$, then $$f^{-1}[A]=\{x\in X:f(x)\in A\}=\varnothing\;,$$ since there are no $x\in X$ such that $f(x)\in A$.

Comment: Oh okay..so it IS null. I'm having trouble with the proof that $X$ is not contractible, since the solution says "g is continuous if and only if $g^{-1}0$, $g^{-1}1,g^{-1}2$... are all open in $\{0\}$" which made me think, "aren't they ALL open anyway since it'll either be mapped to the NULL set of the ENTIRE set $\{0\}$?"

Comment: @John: But there is no homotopy $h:X\times[0,1]\to X$ such that $h(x,0)=x$ for each $x\in X$ and $h(x,1)=0$ for each $x\in X$.